# How to print the background colour of a menu item while hovering the mouse using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am automating a webpage.I have to check the mouse hover functionality works fine or not.
I have to print the background color when mouse is pointed to a particular item.I have written the code but it does not throw the correct out put.

```
public class Selenium_Demos extends Environment_Setup {

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {

            Rapidaction();

    }


    private void Rapidaction() throws Exception
    {
        driver2.get("http://www.rapidvaluesolutions.com/");

        Actions builder = new Actions(driver2);
```

// To click on the link 'PRODUCT'

```
        WebElement td_Home = driver2.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/section[1]/header/nav/ul/li[1]/a"));

        String bgColor = td_Home.getCssValue("background-color");
        System.out.println("Before hover: " + bgColor);

        builder.moveToElement(td_Home).build().perform();

        bgColor = td_Home.getCssValue("background-color");

        System.out.println("After hover: " + bgColor);

        driver2.quit();


    }


}
```

As we point the mouse over the link'Product', the colour of the link - blue should be printed.

Comment: When you first printed bgColor. Was it then printing the color? I mean this line "System.out.println("Before hover: " + bgColor);"

Comment: Nope.The result was :- Before hover: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) After hover: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)

Answer (score 0):

From comment moving to post as I want to post some code.

Can you please change below line

```
 WebElement td_Home = driver2.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/section[1]/header/nav/ul/li[1]/a"));
```

To

```
List<WebElement> td_Home = driver2.findElements(By.xpath("//html/body/section[1]/header/nav/ul/li[1]/a"));
```

And then check what is the length of td_Home i.e. print "`td_Home.size()`"

if the length is more than 1 then you have to debug if it is giving the size as 1 then check some attribute of the element to make sure you have selected a proper element.

Please try this.

**UPDATE:**

Now please do

String bgColor = td_Home.get(0).getCssValue("background-color");

Comment: The size is displayed as 1.So what should I do with the element?

Comment: Throwing the Exception :- java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.WebElement

Comment: You tried this. "String bgColor = td_Home.get(0).getCssValue("background-color");" correct?

Comment: It actually should not as td_Home is a List<WebElement> then you are doing  td_Home.get(0) which will give you the first WebElement and then you do getCssValue("background-color") upon that. So it should work. Can you edit your post and provide the code that you have chenged or the code part where the error is coming.

Answer (score 0):

I have created simple example for you:copy this html in some location and save as .html

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="mydiv" style="width:200px;background:white"  onmouseover="this.style.background='gray';"  onmouseout="this.style.background='white';">
    on mouse over color change.
    </div>
</body>
</html>

     **web driver code:**
     driver.get("file:///C:/Users/vkiran/Desktop/color1.html");

     WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='mydiv']"));

     Actions builder = new Actions(driver);

     Action mouseOver = builder.moveToElement(element).build();

     String bgColor = element.getCssValue("background-color");

     System.out.println("Before hover: " + bgColor);        

     mouseOver.perform();        

     bgColor = element.getCssValue("background-color");

     System.out.println("After hover: " + bgColor);
```

Answer (score 0):

Identify that webelement, then by help of getAttribute() method find the colour

```
System.out.println("Hexadecimal color : "+driver.findElement(By.xpath("write the proper xpath")).getAttribute("bgcolor"));
```

This will give hexadecimal notation for colour

Answer (score 0):

```
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(mycopieslink_locator);
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', 'background: yellow; border: 3px solid red;');", element);
    actions.moveToElement(element);
    actions.click().build().perform();
```